# Iterate through a dictionary and return results in a table

Tags: python

I`m looking at printing the content of a dictionary into a table, the dictionary is defined like this :

```
d = {"date": tuple(date),"open":tuple(open),"close":tuple(close),"min":tuple(min),"max":tuple(max),"gain":tuple(gain),"loss":tuple(loss),"avg_gain":tuple(avg_gain),"avg_loss":tuple(avg_loss)}
```

I would like to iterate through it to print row by row in the shell, the first row would contain the key, and the following rows, the content of tuple(date), tuple(open), etc ...

Comment: no no, just something that looks like rows and columns in the shell, using print '\t' I assume

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about join the key onto the front of the tuple and then use zip(*) to transpose the result

```
>>> d={"A":(1.0,2.0,3.0), "B":(4.0,5.0,6.0), "C":(7.0,8.0,9.0)}
>>> for row in zip(*([k]+map(str,v) for k,v in sorted(d.items()))):
...  print "\t".join(row)
... 
A       B       C
1.0     4.0     7.0
2.0     5.0     8.0
3.0     6.0     9.0
```

Comment: nearly, but I get  print "\t".join(row)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, float found . If I do join(str(row)) then It kinda does it but I only get 1 number each time instead of the full float . ( did I mention the tuples were containing floats ? )

Comment: @Julz, try squeezing a map(str,v) in there

Comment: Tried repr(myFloat) instead? str() will tend towards the human readable, which includes rounding/clipping long floats sometimes.

Answer (score 2):

Unless I'm misunderstanding:

```
for k in d:
    print k, '\t',
for v in d.values():
    print v, '\t',
```

Edit: Perhaps a better way:

```
print '\t'.join(d)
print '\t'.join(d.values())
```

Example:

```
d = {'apple':'green', 'lemon':'yellow', 'cherry':'red'}
```

Output:

```
cherry  lemon   apple
red     yellow  green
```

Comment: this does not quite do it, I think the first row should basically iterate through the keys and print with print '\t',key1,'\t\t'key2 etc ..

Comment: This code **does** iterate through the keys for the first row. They just aren't in the order you expect, because Python dicts **aren't** ordered internally - they're built on hashes, not trees. That's what the `sorted()` call is for in gnibbler's version. This code doesn't, however, expect the dict values to be tuples and split them up row-by-row.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. Yes, I am aware of the lack of ordering. But reading the question again, taken literally, I don't consider an unordered display to be incorrect. But you are right about splitting the tuples. I didn't understand that part of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You could use Pandas (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html) , as long as the tuples are the same length you could do this:

```
>>> import pandas
>>> d={"Green":(1,2,3,4), "Blue":(12,13,14,15), "Red":(1,3,5,7)}
>>> pandas.DataFrame(d)
   Blue  Green  Red
0    12      1    1
1    13      2    3
2    14      3    5
3    15      4    7
```